# Mysql stored procedure with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedure

```
select distinct(movie_id) from movielist where mdate = ?
```

This return movie_id(s) and I need to run 3 sql for each movie_id

```
foreach(movie_id){
    select count(*) as total_viewed from movielist where mdate = ? and movie_id = ? limit 1 //return only one value 
    select count(*) as total_viewed from movielist where mdate like ? and movie_id = ? limit 1 //return only one value
    select count(*) as total_viewed from movielist where mdate like ? and movie_id = ? limit 1 //return only one value

    //Then all the 3 value with movie_id and mdate insert at another table
}
```

Now how to write the stored procedures for this...

Comment: What are you asking about?

Comment: What do you want actually?

Comment: Create a stored procedure with the above details.
Is it possible?

Comment: @DevKamal Please explain your problem with example to understand what actually you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to show the number of views based on each movie

```
 select count(*) as total_viewed from movielist group by movie_id
```

this will show you all the counts based on movie_id

```
 select count(*) as total_viewed from movielist group by mdate,movie_id
```

will show you all counts based on date and movie..

You can use UNION ALL to merge the results (just a hint, can be used, don't know what do you actually want).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cursor, but you do not need at all.

I am not sure what your stored procedure should do, but looks like to give the top 3 viewed movies on a particular day? If so just do

```
select movie_id, count(*) as total_viewed from movielist 
where mdate = ? 
group by movie_id 
order by total_viewed desc 
limit 0,3;
```